# How to re-route a React-Admin url

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-admin

I'm trying to configure the login page for my React-Admin app. I'm using `authProvider` and `LoginPage` components, as per the [documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Tutorial.html) and my login process is generally working.

I have the app running locally on port 3000. But when I go to http://localhost:3000, I'm automatically redirected to http://localhost:3000/#/login.

What specifically is driving that redirection? I don't  specify that .../#/login url within the app itself.

I'm using an old version of React-Admin (2.9), which I understand uses Redux. Is that redirection to .../#/login a function of Redux? Or of React-Admin itself?

My [understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36623117/3368818) [is](https://www.querythreads.com/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-the-url-in-react-router/) I can maybe use HashHistory or BrowserHistory to prevent the # - but not sure if that's compatible with React-Admin.

The actual issue I'm having is that once I deploy the app to my domain, the login process behaves differently compared to when I run on localhost - which is making pre-deployment testing difficult.

That is, http://localhost:3000 and http://localhost:3000/#/login both allow me to login successfully. But when I deploy to my domain, http://www.example.com allows me to login, while http://www.example.com/#/login does not.

Any idea why this would be? And can I configure a React-Admin app to *not* re-route to http://www.example.com/#/login?

Comment: I can't find anything in the doc but as a workaround you can customize the `<Login>` component and put a `<Redirect>` to your root in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"If the promise is rejected, react-admin redirects by default to the /login page.
You can override where to redirect the user in checkAuth(), by rejecting an object with a redirectTo property:"

React-admuin 2.9:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/2.9/Authentication.html#checking-credentials-during-navigation

```
// in src/authProvider.js (React-admin 2.9)
import { AUTH_LOGIN, AUTH_LOGOUT, AUTH_ERROR, AUTH_CHECK } from 'react-admin';

export default (type, params) => {
    if (type === AUTH_LOGIN) {
        // ...
    }
    if (type === AUTH_LOGOUT) {
        // ...
    }
    if (type === AUTH_ERROR) {
        // ...
    }
    if (type === AUTH_CHECK) {
        return localStorage.getItem('token') ? Promise.resolve() : Promise.reject({ redirectTo: '/no-access' });
    }
    return Promise.reject('Unknown method');
};
```

React-admin 4.3: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/AuthProviderWriting.html

```
// in src/authProvider.js
export default {
    login: ({ username, password }) => { /* ... */ },
    checkError: (error) => { /* ... */ },
    checkAuth: () => localStorage.getItem('auth')
        ? Promise.resolve()
        : Promise.reject({ redirectTo: '/no-access' }),
    // ...
}
```

Comment: You're quoting something from the doc of the latest version but OP specified they are using RA 2.9. [The property `redirectTo` seems to be an option available for the old version too.](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/2.9/Authentication.html#checking-credentials-during-navigation)

Comment: Arkellys, yes you are right, added the answer.